# Removing Invalid Parentheses - Leetcode Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I was solving this problem on leetcode and the problem statement is as follows.

Remove the minimum number of invalid parentheses in order to make the input string valid. Return all possible results.

Note: The input string may contain letters other than the parentheses ( and ).

```
Examples:
"()())()" -> ["()()()", "(())()"]
"(a)())()" -> ["(a)()()", "(a())()"]
")(" -> [""]
```

I was able to solve the problem after a while. But I'm not able to find the time complexity of my solution. My code is as follows. Please help me find the time complexity.

```
    class Solution {
public:

    void balance(string s, int curr_index, int changes, int max_changes, unordered_set<string> &memo, vector<string> &result){

        if(memo.find(s) != memo.end()){
            return;
        }

        if(changes == max_changes){
            int opening = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
                if(s[i] == '('){
                    opening++;
                }
                else if(s[i] == ')'){
                    if(opening == 0){
                        return;
                    }
                    else{
                        opening--;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(opening == 0){
                result.push_back(s);
            }
        }
        else if(changes > max_changes || curr_index >= s.length()){
            return;
        }
        else{
            if(s[curr_index] == '(' || s[curr_index] == ')'){
                string temp = s;
                temp.erase(temp.begin() + curr_index);
                balance(temp, curr_index, changes + 1, max_changes, memo, result);
            }

            balance(s, curr_index + 1, changes, max_changes, memo, result);
        }

        memo.insert(s);

    }


    vector<string> removeInvalidParentheses(string s) {

        int opening = 0;
        int min_changes = 0;

        vector<string> result;

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            if(s[i] == ')' && opening == 0){
                min_changes++;
            }
            else if(s[i] == ')' && opening != 0){
                opening--;
            }
            else if(s[i] == '('){
                opening++;
            }
        }

        min_changes += opening;

        if(min_changes == s.length()){
            result.push_back("");
            return result;
        }
        else{

            unordered_set<string> memo;

            balance(s, 0, 0, min_changes, memo, result);

            return result;
        }

    }
    };
```

Comment: The time complexity for the above seems to be `O(n!2^n)`. But you can actually improve it using the BFS solution for this question. Time complexity in that case comes to be around `O(n!)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exponential. There's nothing you can do about because the output size may be exponential.

Consider the following example: `(a(a(a(a.....))))))`, where the number of pairs `(a` is twice the number of closing parenthesis. It's clear that we need to remove exactly half of the opening parenthesis, and it's also clear that removing any their subset  yield a unique string.

Let the length of the string be `5n`. Then we have `2n` '(' and 'a' and `n` ')'.  There are `2n` choose `n` ways to remove a subset of opening parenthesis and get a valid string, which is an exponent in the length of the string.

Comment: Yeah. I think it should be of order `n2^n`?

Comment: @CodeHunter It's possible to get a more precise bound using central binomial coefficient  approximation formulas. But the thing is, I can't prove that my example is the worst case. There might be others with even faster growing exponents.

Comment: @CodeHunter How is the complexity exponential? I mean I've memoized here. The two recursive calls depend only on the curr_index parameter which ranges from 0 to n. And I have a for loop which ranges from 0 to n. So isn't the complexity O(n^3)? Please clear my confusion.

Comment: @Srivathsan: Try doing the steps done by your algorithm manually by yourself on an input like `((((`. You'll find that this will be one of the worst case for this scenario. Check how many steps are you doing. Also, I did this question sometime back and the best approach I knew worked in `O(n!)` time. If you can work it out in `O(n^3)` as you stated, it is really good. But I don't think this is `O(n^3)` here.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit of an older question, but I just wanted to note that in every implementation I'm aware of, the string building is O(n) and you have O(2 ^ n) leaves, as noted above. So O(n * 2 ^ n) is the correct time complexity.